# simulink-matlab function-variable size matrix

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I have a Matlab function block in Simulink, which would like to be a modulator. 
It gets a  `[40000x1]` input and should return a `[51x1]` output, the function work as finding the turning points from the input signal.
but there is always a problem while compile.

'Data 'ext' is inferred as a variable size matrix, while its properties in the Model Explorer specify its size as inherited or fixed'

the simplified code is showed below:

```
function ext= sig2ext(sig)

sig=sig(:);

w1=diff(sig); 

w=logical([1;(w1(1:end-1).*w1(2:end))<=0;1]);

ext=sig(w);
```

Comment: How do you know that `w` will always have exactly 51 `true` elements?

Comment: sorry for not make it clearly. it is not always 51 true elements, it is just an example, but the output number is always smaller than the input number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that the signals, or specifically in your case, the output signal is variable sized.  There is quite an extensive set of documentation that describes to do this: [Variable Size Data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/variable-size-data.html).

I'd recommend that you start by looking at the [Filter a Variable Size Signal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/filter-a-variable-size-signal.html) which walks through all the steps described on the other doc pages.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers, I check the output block into variable sized, but the following error shows. 

Simulink cannot propagate the variable-size mode from the output port. The variable-size mode originates from 'untitled/MATLAB Function/ SFunction '. Examine the configurations of 'untitled/To File' for one of the following scenarios: 1) the block does not support variable-size signals; 2) the block supports variable-size signals but needs to be configured for them.

Comment: MATLAB Function blocks do support variable sized signals, so you haven't configured your block correctly.